# Woocommerce - Set minimum quantity and step only for products in the cart that have a certain attribute

Tags: woocommerce, attributes, cart, product-quantity

I'm working on a woocommerce site for selling wines. I would like to set the multiple purchase value (step) only for products that have a specific attribute.

Each product is sold in bottles which can be 1 ltr, 2 liters or 3 liters. So the "bottle" attribute (=>pa_bottle) has 3 terms: 1liter, 2liters, 3liters.

I want the cart to be considered valid when the total of items with attribute "1liter" is a multiple of 3.

For example, this cart is valid:

- 1 x Prosecco wine - attribute 1liter
- 2 x  Prosecco wine - attribute 3liters
- 2 x Champagne wine - attribute 1liter

I found a script that works perfectly for category. I would like a similar script that works for the attribute.

This is the original script:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'woocommerce_check_cart_quantities' );
function woocommerce_check_cart_quantities() {
$multiples = 3;
$total_products = 0;
$category_ids = array( 74 );
$found = false;

foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
    if ( has_product_category( $cart_item['product_id'], $category_ids ) ) {
        
        $total_products += $cart_item['quantity'];
        $found = true;
    }
}
if ( ( $total_products % $multiples ) > 0 && $found )
    wc_add_notice( sprintf( __('You need to buy in quantities of %s products', 'woocommerce'), $multiples ), 'error' );
}
```

Here I tried to replace the script

```
if ( has_product_category( $cart_item['product_id'], $category_ids ) ) {
```

with the script

```
if ( has_term( '1liter', 'pa_bottle', $cart_item['product_id'] ) ) {
```

but it doesn't work because it sets the step value on all the products in the cart, while I would like it to set it only on those with the 1liter attribute.

Thanks for help me.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found the solution.
Here is the working code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items','woocommerce_check_cart_quantities' );

function woocommerce_check_cart_quantities() {

$multiples = 3;
$total_products = 0;
$found = false;
$attribute_slug_term = '1liter';

foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {

    if( $cart_item['variation_id'] > 0 ){
            // Loop through product attributes values set for the variation
            foreach( $cart_item['variation'] as $term_slug ){
                // comparing attribute term value with current attribute value
                if ( $term_slug === $attribute_slug_term ) {
                  $total_products += $cart_item['quantity'];
                  $found = true;
                  break; // Stop current loop
                }
            }
        }
}
if ( ( $total_products % $multiples ) > 0 && $found )
    wc_add_notice( sprintf( __('You need to buy in quantities of %s products', 'woocommerce'), $multiples ), 'error' );
```

}